# How to get accurate/fresh POIs with Map tiles REST API?

Tags: here-api

A tile sent from Nokia Here-Map tiles API, contains at least two POIs that do not exists in real life and also not on other Map services like Google Maps and OpenStreetMap. How can i get accurate/fresh POIs with the Map Tiles Api?

I'm using the service with LeafletJs, and i use a hybrid.day base map and a base one, with the pois parameter set to true and map version set to "newest". The tiles i'm getting effectively contains POIs but it doesn't seem accurate. I wrote to the sales support at Nokia Here, i'm not sure they can help me, but the website also indicate to use stackoverflow for technical questions. Mine doesn't seem like a sales related question or a technical one but i see no other alternative contact.

This is a link to get a tile with incorrect POIs:
https://4.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/bd9e007617/normal.day/17/59178/60113/256/png8?app_id=mVrBstuYsfUVga31l6IX&app_code=xphvU-Uj071dI-UkNaxMrg&lg=fre&pois=true&style=default

The tile contains two POIs that do not exists in real life or on other map services like OpenStreetMap. The two are: "Ecobank" and "Restorant Aku".

The place the map shows is around these coordinates: lat:14.729235451930021
lng:-17.46165559897639

The returned tile shouldn't contains inexistant POIs.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error in HERE database. You should report it through [HERE Map Creator](http://mapcreator.here.com)

Comment: Thank you, i've just used Map Creator to remove the two problematic places. Since it's the first time i use the Creator, i do not know if that suffice or how long it'll take to update the tile served by the Map tile api, can you enlighten me a little more, please?

Answer (score 0):

It will go through some kind of quality moderation, so it may take a few weeks. Maybe adding a fresh photo would speed up things.